# Adding more than 18 figures

Tags: latex

I am new to LaTeX. I am not able to add more than 18 figures in LaTeX in the document class `article` not in `thesis`.

Could anyone suggest me how to add more than 18 figures?

Comment: I had the same problemL 18 figures was the max. If you add \clearpage somewhere between the figures, it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s no restriction on the number of figures (well, except due to limitations in the system but that number is much higher).

18 pictures are totally fine. The problem is elsewhere.